# JavaScript Moments Format Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, momentjs

Salaamun Alekum

I Want To Change DateTime Format To Short Date Format 
My Current Date Is

> "Sunday 31 January 2016 12:00:00 AM"

I Want To Change It To Short Date

```
'DD/MM/YYYY'
```

I Tried To Use Moment JS Library But Is Giving Error While I Use The Following Code

```
moment("Sunday 31 January 2016 12:00:00 AM", "MM-DD-YYYY").format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

On Using This Command Error Is Given To Me

> "Invalid date"

I need Guidance On This

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
moment("Sunday 31 January 2016 12:00:00 AM", "dddd D MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss A").format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

**When you create a date with moment, the first string is the date you want to parse, and se second one is the format of that string.**

You can check how to parse dates with momentjs [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

`dddd` is for `Monday...Sunday`

`MMMM` is for `January...December`

and so on...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"dddd DD MMMM YYYY ..."`? Would `D`not reference to a single character day from 1 - 9?

Comment: @Aer0 no, `D` is for not show a `01` as a day when the day is `1`... if you want to force it to use 2 digits, you should use `DD` instead of `D`. You know what I mean?

Comment: Yeah, I see. Thanks so far. :)

Comment: @Aer0 but... I'm trying and In this case (for create the date) seems like it doesn't matter. I mean if you do `moment("Sunday 1 January 2016 12:00:00 AM", "dddd DD MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss A")` it gets the date without warning, but if you want to format it, is not the same `.format('DD/MM/YYYY');` than `.format('D/M/YYYY');`. The first one is going to print **`01/01/2016`** and the second one **`1/1/2016`**.